# Which action is chosen in case of a tie?

Tags: stack-egg

If two (or more) people force a tie between say, Answering and Closing, what happens? Do both actions occur? Does it pick the first action chosen or are they chosen at random?

Further: Are certain actions weighted over others, so a tie between say, Flagging and Answering, will Answering always win out?

Comment: I noticed that with resetting, if it is a tie, it'll always default to continue.

Comment: I am not 100% sure but I am 99% sure that in case of 2. (I actually did this with someone on arqade), it will choose the first answer.

Comment: @aman207 Nope. I had three categories up to four stars, and were working on my fifth, when someone decided to reset. Three times in a row we tied and continued. The fourth time it actually reset. :'(

Comment: The core code is out on [GitHub](https://github.com/StackExchange/stackegg/tree/master/StackEgg), since I barely know javascript but what I understand it is decided by whichever last action is returned by the Console since that is the [console version of the code](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/252575/227881) (mentioned in comments), the UI part we used would return its value differently.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The actions was chosen randomly between the tied winners (which was the only element of randomness in the game).